# The backward addition of two array with different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays

I have two array with different dimensions as follows

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

b=np.array([[4,5,6],[5,8,9]])
```

How can I get the c, let the

```
c[-1]=a[-1]+b[-1],   c[-2]= a[-2]+b[-2]
```

that is:
`c=[[8,10,12],[12,16,18]]`
I have tried as follows, but the result is not right.

```
import numpy as np
c=list()
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b=np.array([[4,5,6],[5,8,9]])
for i in range(len(b)):
    b= a[-(len(b)+1-i)] + b
    c.append(b)
    print(c)
```

Comment: You mean `a[-2:] + b`?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I got array([[ 8, 10, 12],  [ 9, 13, 15]]) from a[-2:] + b. I want got c=[[8,10,12],[12,16,18]] , in which the last lines of each array can add with each other.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried the follows, it seems right. c=list()
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b=np.array([[4,5,6],[5,8,9]])                                                          
for i in range(len(b)-1):
    b= a[i-(len(b)):] + b[i-(len(b)):]
    c.append(b)
    print(c)

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. With the given sample, `a[-2:] + b` yields `array([[ 8, 10, 12], [12, 16, 18]])`

Comment: Thanks Chris，you are right.